# In Visual Studio console app, code work but not when I use it in an Azure function app

Tags: azure, function

In a Visual Studio console app,I have the following code and it works

```
var accessTokenInfo = Configuration.Default.ApiClient.PostToken("**********", "***************");
```

But when I use the same line of code in an Azure function app, it gives the error

```cs
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error , **`FileNotFoundException`**, indicates that the required assembly **`System.Text.Json` version 7.0.0.0** is not found. This can happen if the assembly reference is not correctly configured in your Azure Function app project.

I changed the **System.Text.Json** to **Version="7.0.3"** and can able to run a simple functions code,

[image]

I can able to run a simple function code with that package.

**Code** :

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp37
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            var json = "{\"message\": \"Hello, JSON!\"}";
            var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
            var root = jsonDocument.RootElement;
            var message = root.GetProperty("message").GetString();

            response.WriteString($"Message from JSON: {message}");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above output URL, I got below in the browser,

[image]